# The number of tiles i am receiving is same as my posts length but i am not getting the data from posts, and getting and error instead of data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new with firebase and I am trying this code to retrieve data

```
Future getPosts() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot response =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").get();
      return response.docs;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e;
    }
  }
```

And to list data I'm using this

```
class GridViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context).getPosts(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading..."),
            );
          } else {
            return GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return PostGridTile(
                    snapshot.data[index].data.id,
                    snapshot.data[index].data.title,
                    snapshot.data[index].data.imageUrl,
                  );
                });
          }
        });
  }
}
```

The post model i am using

```
class Posts {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String price;
  String imageUrl;
  // bool isFavourite;

  Posts.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    title = data['title'];
    description = data['description'];
    price = data['price'];
    imageUrl = data['imageUrl'];
  }
  // Posts({this.id, this.description, this.imageUrl, this.price, this.title});
}
```

Well I am getting the number of gridtiles same as the amount of posts i have in my cloud firestore but instead of showing my data it's giving error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'id'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: id
Found: id() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

If I remove the id from the code it'll give same error  for title and other fields.

Any type of help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
snapshot.data[index]["title"]
```

or you can also convert to model

```
Posts post = Posts.fromMap(snapshot.data[index].data());
```

and then use **post** object as `post.id` `post.title`

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: docs

Comment: After using the first code snapshot.data.docs[index].data["title"] this is what i got

Comment: remove docs, because i noticed that you already returning docs. check my updated answer now

Comment: After removing the error i got is .... The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: []("id")
Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: which version of firestore dependency are you using?

Comment: firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
  
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0

Comment: Okay, so according to new dep. `data[index]["id"]` will work

Comment: I've updated my answer with latest version

Answer (score 0):

Just change this and it'll work

```
snapshot.data[index]["id"],
```